# Not able to setup React native project on windows

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, android-sdk-manager

Hi I have followed the [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) for setting up the React native project on windows.
I have added the ANDROID_HOME variable as system variable at location

"C:\Users\AKSHAY\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
[image]

In the second step I was supposed to add Environment variable at

"C:\Android\tools\bin\platform-tools"

but there is no tools folder in Android instead I found platform-tools under SDK below is the location

"C:\Users\AKSHAY\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools"

Now when I am running

> npx react-native run android

I am getting the below attached error

[image]

Here is the SDK folder
[image]
Please help.

Comment: As far as I know the error is not with AVD instead with the license

Answer (score 0):

if your RN >=.62

You can run  npx react-native doctor inside your project folder

else

run npx @react-native-community/cli doctor inside your project folder

This command checks your environment and displays a report of the status of react native installation. Check the output carefully for other software you might need to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can install android studio then add ANDROID_HOME to your ENV Variable and point to your SDK.

**Follow this link:** https://web.archive.org/web/20180210044548/http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/

Answer (score 0):

The path you are looking for is located at :
C:\Users\"yourUser"\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools