# Android Version Not found while running npx react-native doctor

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, npx

So I asked a question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996289/not-able-to-setup-react-native-project-on-windows) about setting up react native environment for windows. But I got error about android licensing so someone suggested me to run **npx react-native doctor** which resulted in one error which is

[image: this error]
Here is the list of SDK installed
[image]
Please help me what does this error means

Comment: It is likely that your environment variable path is not properly setup on android. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059029/6299120

Comment: I have added the system variable ANDROID_HOME at "C:\Users\AKSHAY\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms"           that is at the location mentioned in the above above screenshot . Do I have to do something else

Comment: Incase your sdk is installed on other location. Can you verify if it is on C:\Users\AKSHAY\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms? maybe some type error

Comment: I guess SDK is installed in the above location only. And what do you mean by type error

Comment: shouldn't SDK be at the above screenshot that I added?

Comment: Right. I usually work on mac so might not be updated on widows setup but. https://medium.com/@prasadjivane/react-native-environment-setup-on-windows-10-47a3b5e833b9 end of this installation guide can be useful

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on windows 10:

Install android command line tools from android studio SDK manager (SDK tools tab). then add `<YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH>\cmdline-tools\latest\bin` to PATH environment variables

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID_HOME should be set to: C:\Users\AKSHAY\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Have you checked that your sdkmanager is properly working??

Try sdkmanager --list